# Perform filtering on whole left outer join set

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, left-join, entity-attribute-value, sequelize-typescript

I have a query which does a left outer join via an id and looks like the following (simplyfied):

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`firstName`, `user`.`lastName`, 
       `user_details`.`value` AS `user_details.value`, `user_details`.`key` AS `user_details.key`
FROM `users` AS `user` LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `user_details` AS `details`
     ON `user`.`id` = `user_details`.`userId`
```

I am using sequelize to generate this query.
What I want to do is filter every user depending on one specific entry in the user_details table. So for example I have some users which has three items in the user_details table. One of the has the key `city` and the value `Berlin`. I want to perform a query which returns a list of users which have all the city set to Berlin, but I want not just those matches with value being Berlin but for those users I want all relations to their user_details items.

What would be the SQL way of doing this? (I am using `mysql 8.0.18-google`)
And could this be done with build-in sequelize functionalities?

I tried this:

```
User.findAll({
  include: [UserDetails],
  where: {
            [Op.and]: {
              '$user_details.key$': 'city',
              '$user_details.value$': 'Berlin'
            }
          }
})
```

But this just returns the users and the one relation matching the city.

Edit: To clear things up, some example data

User Data

```
| name   | age | id |
|--------|-----|----|
| Franz  | 34  | 1  |
| Holger | 42  | 2  |
```

User Details

```
| key    | value     | userId |
|--------|-----------|--------|
| city   | Berlin    | 1      |
| Holger | Frankfurt | 2      |
| gender | male      | 1      |
| gender | male      | 2      |
```

Current Result (with sequelize query)

```
| id |  name | age | key  | value  |
|----|-------|-----|------|--------|
| 1  | Franz | 34  | city | Berlin |
```

Wanted Result with filtering by the user details city

```
| id |  name | age | key    | value  |
|----|-------|-----|--------|--------|
| 1  | Franz | 34  | city   | Berlin |
| 1  | Franz | 34  | gender | male   |
```

**Current (very ugly and surely quite slow) solution**

Adding this to the query:

```
attributes: {
  include: [
    [Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT COUNT(ud.userId) from user_details AS ud WHERE ud.value like '%${keyword}%' and ud.key = 'city' and ud.userId = user_details.userId GROUP BY ud.userId)`), 'num_city']
  ]
},
```

(user_details coming from the "outside" query).

And then adding then checking for this below like

```
having: {
  '$num_city$': {
     [Op.gte]: 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What does `user_details` look like?

Comment: There's no user table here. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want all rows where the user has three rows with `'city'`/`'berlin'`.  If so, window function can do this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, 
       ud.value AS `user_details.value`, ud.key AS `user_details.key`
FROM payees p JOIN
     (SELECT ud.*,
             SUM(value = 'city' and key = 'Berlin') OVER (PARTITION BY ud.userid) as num_city_berlin
      FROM user_details ud
     ) ud
     ON u.id = ud.userId
WHERE num_city_berlin = 3;
```

Note that `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate, because you are requiring that there be a match.

If you want *any* row in Berlin, you can just change the `= 3` to `>= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Key-value schema is both inefficient and clumsy.  If this is a common query, add a column to `users` called `city`.

Meanwhile...

As I understand the desired query, you want "all the attributes of Berliners".

```
SELECT  u.`id`, u.`firstName`, u.`lastName`,
        ud.key, ud.value
    FROM ( SELECT user_id FROM user_details
               WHERE key = 'city'
                 AND value = 'Berlin'
         ) AS berliners
    JOIN user_details AS ud  ON ud.user_id = berliners.user_id
    JOIN users AS u  ON berliners.user_id = u.id
```

Indexing:

```
user_details:  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, key)
user_details:  INDEX(key, value)
user_details:  no AUTOINCREMENT column
```

If `value` is a `TEXT` column, the index-prefix kludge may be necessary:

```
user_details:  INDEX(key, value(50))
```